# making a dicomdir-File useing dcmtk: useing "absolute" Path?

Tags: dicom

I want to create a dicmdir file using dcmmkdir where the file-path isn't the same as the dicomdir-path.

Example:

> File stored in *`C:\Dicompath`* 
>   Dicomdir should be stored in *`H:\tmp`*

```
dcmmkdir -v +r -Pmi +D H:\tmp\ +id C:\Dicompath\
```

Does anybody know what I have to do getting my vision?

thanks

GGK

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for the associated [dcmgpdir](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/dcmgpdir.html) application, you need to specify a *file name* with the `+D` option. For most reliable outcome, I also believe you need to specify a (dummy) file name pattern with option `+p`:

```
dcmmkdir -v +r -Pmi +D H:\tmp\DICOMDIR +id C:\Dicompath\ +p *.*
```

Comment: Thanks for answering really quickly. Your are right with your first comment (I missed to insert the filename in my post), but second hint doesn't do what I want. Files referenced in dicomdir file are not be found by my dicomviewer

Comment: OK, I see your point. But looking at the definition for the *Referenced File ID* tag *(0004,1500)* in the DICOM Standard, I think it will be awkward to represent an absolute (Windows) file path; it is a *Code String* (CS) attribute that can take 1-8 values (directories and file name) each up to 8 characters long. *Code Strings* only support uppercase letters A-Z, digits 0-9, space and underscore, so a relative path using `..` would also not be supported. In practice, you are probably confined to placing your DICOMDIR file at the root of your DICOM file directory.

Comment: Ok...thats I do actually. My Problem is, that users don't have reading access at the c-disk and the h-disk is a shared diskspace with quota. So I dont like to write dicomfile on h-drive an create dicomdir there. I would prefer writing dicomfiles on c-disk and create dicomdir on h. seems to bo no way to do this.